# Hierarchical regression with dummy variables

Tags: multiple-regression, multilevel-analysis

I need to perform hierarchical regression with dummy variables. I also need to check moderation by introducing in the model interactions of these dummy variables and the moderator. My questions are:

1. Do I introduce in the model a number of dummy variables which is equal to the total number of predictors minus 1, making the absent variable the reference category?
2. How do I interpret the results, given presence of the reference category?
3. For interactions, do I multiply the dummy variables (categorical level) by the moderator (interval level, measured on a 1-5 Likert scale)?

Thanks for your time and any ideas are much appreciated.

Kind regards
Muzi

Comment: What is the nature of your response variable (dependent variable)? Is it a Likert scale, or a continuous variable or what?

Comment: The dependent variable was measured on a 1-5 Likert Scale, Thanks

Comment: What software package are you using?